# Why does vm.swappiness not working?

Tags: 20.04, swap

```
 ~ uname -a
Linux user 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 ~ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
 5

 ~ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       6.0Gi       123Mi       1.1Gi       1.5Gi       278Mi
Swap:         3.8Gi       2.0Gi       1.8Gi
```

The same behavior was on Ubuntu 18.04 and I thought on Ubuntu 20.04 the issue will be resolved, but I am getting the same problem.

It's doesn't matter if I use swap file or zram, setting vm.swappiness never works.

As requested:

```
top - 21:46:46 up 13 min,  2 users,  load average: 3.86, 3.82, 2.20
Tasks: 268 total,   3 running, 265 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 39.0 us, 14.0 sy,  0.1 ni, 46.8 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7858.1 total,    146.8 free,   5743.9 used,   1967.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   3960.5 free,    135.5 used.    971.5 avail Mem

 ~ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Nothing can be said about this without knowing the use pattern, when the system last rebooted, etc.. If a tone time the swap is needed, it will be involved. Even if there is again plenty of free memory, swapped memory may continue to sit in the swap it it was not needed in the mean time. You will need to boot fresh and then document the history of memory usage in connection to things you do before one can tell if the behaviour is normal or not.

Comment: You don't understand what vm.swappiness does, and 5 is definitely the WRONG value for your configuration. What are you expecting it to do? Set it back to 60. Have you manually installed any "swap" apps like zram, swap compression, or other? Your swap usage is a little high... depending on what you're running. Edit your question and show me `top` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I've rebooted, launched a bunch of programs and at 5.5 GB RAM usage system started swapping.
I am expecting for the system to start swapping when there 5% or less RAM available. I've done it for experiment but usually I have it at 10.
Yeas, after initial installation I've deleted swap file and installed zram but now I am again with swap file. My swap usage in above example so high because I've deliberately opened a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, 5.4 kernel has something off in the VM system.

In 5.4 kernel series, I can have like 4GB of applications running on my 16GB system at home, do something involving like 5-10GB+ of disk I/O, and eventually I have like 2GB+ swapped out... and a nice big swapin pause if I pull down menus or whatever.  It does seem setting vm.swappiness=1 versus vm.swapiness=100 versus default has little to no effect on 5.4.x kernels.

In pre-5.4 kernels I ran in Ubuntu 18.04, and also with 5.7.x kernel I ran in Ubuntu 18.04 with mainline (Ubuntu mainline kernel installer), if you set vm.swappiness=100 it was still not quite as aggressive with the swap as 5.4 is.  Not that I recommend a value as low as vm.swappiness=1, but in 5.4.x series it seems to still swap pretty heavily, in pre-5.4 and post-5.4 kernels if I ran enough apps it would let applications virtually fill RAM before it swapped, which lead to pretty bad performance due to the tiny amount of RAM left for the disk cache; it did indeed show near-zero swap usage until RAM was pretty full.

Comment: Thank you for providing more information. I had a hunch that the problem lies within the kernel.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem since I've upgraded my Debian systems from Buster to Bullseyes which uses a 5.10.x kernel. The problem however starts when swap is actually needed, once used it's never ever released and the problem will be just like described above. So it works well until the memory is filled and then it will start swapping way more than actually needed making the machine barely useable and causing long swapping IO pauses... vm.swappiness has no effect on this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to increase `vm.watermark_scale_factor` (great [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/anticipating-your-memory-needs) on this topic)

`sudo sysctl -w vm.watermark_scale_factor=1000` should have the effect that you're looking for :

When free memory goes below 10% (where `10 := watermark_scale_factor / 100`), the kernel will wake *kswapd* and will thus swap out memory pages to the swap (or discard cache pages, **this** actually depends on `vm.swappiness`) until free memory goes up to 20%

Useful reference : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt